# $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ acts continuously on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Consider the group action $GL(n,\mathbb{R})\times \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n, (A,x)\mapsto A.x$, where $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is the topological group obtained by endowing the general linear group with the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the Euclidean space.

I want to show that this action $GL(n,\mathbb{R})\times \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n, (A,x)\mapsto A.x$ is continuous. The problem comes from John M. Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds, Example 3.35. At this point, the only ways to show that action is continuous is by defintion or if you know the topological group is a discrete group then one can check if $X\to X$, $x\mapsto A.x$ is continuous for each $A$ in the group.

There is one other thing I could try: Show that for each $A\in GL(n,\mathbb{R})$, $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and for each neighbourhood $U_{A.x}$ of $A.x$, there are neighbouroods $U_A$, $U_x$ such that $U_A.U_x:=\{B.y|B\in U_A, y\in U_x\}\subset U_{A.x}$. This comes from something I saw on wikipidea page for topological groups on how to show that the product map in the definition of topological groups is continuous.

I would very much appreciate both methods specific to this problem and general suggestions to show continuity of functions of the form $X\times Y\to Z$. I feel more comfortable with maps into product spaces rather than out of them.

Comment: $\|Ax-By\| \le \|A\|\|x-y\| + \|A-B\|\|x-y\| + \|A-B\|\|x\|$ and this is enough to prove continuity

Comment: If you write out the formula it's a polynomial in each factor.

Comment: So does it go something like: The co-efficients of the column vector $A.x$ are of the form $a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+.....+a_{1n}x_n$, which is a polynomial in co-efficients of $A$ and $x$ and hence continuous. Since each of the co-efficients is continuous, $(A,x)\mapsto A.x$ is itself continuous?

Comment: So the action combines 'parts' of the group element and the topological point in a 'polynomial' fashion in each co-efficient. Can we say that the action is a polynomial function in each co-efficient?